# webp images are not getting published

Tags: publishing, web8.5, dd4t-2, binary

I am attaching a webp image in richtext editor, but the image is not getting published. I am using DD4T template and SDL web 8.5.

Is there any additional configuration needs be done other than new multimedia settings on administration?

Comment: Are you sure the image is not getting published? Or could the problem be further down the line? Have you run your template in template builder to verify that the images end up in the package?